# VB.Net program not working in other system

Tags: .net, vb.net, invalidoperationexception

I have basic knowledge in VB, I have created an VB application through Visual Studio 2012 with target .net framework 4.5. The application runs fine in few system and in few system the program crashes while opening. I receive the following message

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: bom check.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5b2b1fd5
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba22001
  Problem Signature 07: 105d
  Problem Signature 08: 1c
  Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    16393
  Additional Information 1: d426
  Additional Information 2: d4265dda6372144af1b6ce81a2254bff
  Additional Information 3: 511b
  Additional Information 4: 511b498149bf18a02ba8e84de7858a3e
```

I couldn't fix this issue.

Comment: What's the stack trace?  What's the exception message?  Where in your code is the exception thrown?  It sounds like you need to start catching and logging errors in your application so you can get information about the problem.

Comment: You should be handling the `UnhandledException` event in every VB.NET application in order to catch unexpected exceptions.  That allows you to log the error and shut down gracefully instead of crashing. Once you know what happened and where, you'll have a chance of diagnosing the issue.  At least you'll have more relevant information to provide to us.

Comment: @David, when I start the application I receive this message.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney when I run the same application in other system it performs well.

Comment: @ManjunathSubramaniam: That's nice, but that's not the point.  The point is that what you have here provides no useful information about the exception.  Step one is to *gather information* about the problem.  *Then* you can correct the problem.  In this case you'd gather information by adding error handling and logging to your application and then re-deploying.  Handle and log all exceptions, get as much debugging information as you can.